# How to upload the mobi file into dropbox using xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, dropbox

How can we upload the .mobi file into dropbox in a button click using xamarin Android?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [Xamarin.Dropbox.Api](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) in your project:

[image]

Then check the document here: [tutorial](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/dotnet#tutorial).

The code for uploading is like this:

```
public async Task Upload(DropboxClient dbx, string folder, string file, string content)
{
    using (var mem = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content)))
    {
        var updated = await dbx.Files.UploadAsync(
            folder + "/" + file,
            WriteMode.Overwrite.Instance,
            body: mem);
        Console.WriteLine("Saved {0}/{1} rev {2}", folder, file, updated.Rev);
    }
}
```